# Power requried for M-ary modulation schemes

Tags: power, modulation

When we go for M-ary modulation schemes like QPSK etc, does the transmission power increase with M? Why?

Comment: In textbooks, you might find something [like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CvwV4.png), but they don't ask themselves the same [simple and somewhat irrelevant] question that you asked, but rather are concerned with energy [or power] per bit needed to meet a certain BER... and given a certain fading model, e.g. AWGN. That's plotted on the Y axis there.

Comment: +1 for the title "Power of **Mary** modulation schemes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QPSK (quadrature phase shift keying) uses a modulating signal that produces no discernible change in amplitude (or power) because the 4 modulation amplitudes are held constant i.e. they are all on the circumference of a circle: -

[image]

This results in a time domain waveform typical of below: -

[image]

You can even take this further to 8-psk: -

[image]

So, the basic power remains the same for any m-ary purely-PSK system. However, there are variations and these have similar constellation patterns but there is amplitude modulation as well: -

[image]

Given that 4 out of the 16 bit combinations are centred further out than the others could mean the average power is greater but, there are also 4 bit combinations that are smaller than the others two so, given that these differences cancel out over time, you could argue that the net power is the same.

Comment: Power is usually measured per bit for communication schemes. But given that who asked has no idea about that... your answer suits him.